# Wireshark capture ARP traffic and EAPOL

Tags: wireshark, sniffing

I'm trying to capture only ARP traffic and EAPOL on wireshark. I'm using the following capture filter:

```
ether proto 0x888e or arp
```

But I only capture EAPOL traffic. On the other hand using the following display filter I can see ARP and EAPOL.

```
eapol or arp
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm talking about capture filters, not display filters. Each single filters works right, but using both at the same time don't work as expected.

Comment: Take a look at captured headers. Capture filters only match against the _outermost_ Ethernet header, while display filters match against Ethernet anywhere in the stack.

Comment: The idea is capture real time packets for a long time (maybe days or weeks), use dedicated hardware to do it. In my opinion, using capture filters instead of display filters could help to remains low the number of captured packets. That's something I'm worried about, because is not 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Right now I'm using both because I'm unable to capture EAPOL and ARP, if I could, I would only use the capture filter @Biswapriyo

Comment: Probable filter: `ether proto 0x888e or ether proto 0x0806`

Comment: If this is on Wi-Fi, remember that ARP will be encrypted (and thus not hit your filter) unless you can decrypt it. If this is WPA2-PSK you’ll need to tell Wireshark the SSID and passphrase of the network, and capture the full eapol handshake of each client as it (re-)joins the network. If this is WPA2-enterprise, you’re not going to be able to decrypt it.

Comment: @Spiff thank you for your answer, that's exactly what I am doing, I'm getting EAPOL messages so that using password+ESSID I can decrypt ARP messages. I'm going to test again those filters and see if it work.

Comment: @Biswapriyo using both filters I only capture EAPOL messages, in my opinion maybe I need another packets to be able to decrypt WiFi traffic. Thank you for your time and all your answer. I will continue investigating.